# The best way to pre-configure all instances of WebClient globally?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

TL;DR - I am looking for the best way to provide all instances of WebClient in a single application some base configurations, like defining a timeout, by defining it in a single piece of code.

I need to be able to manage the configuration of WebClient objects in multiple springboot projects. The goal is to make sure that these projects are following certain policies.
For example, all WebClient objects instantiated in each of these projects should have `CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS` set to 1000 miliseconds. Another example is manipulating the request header of each request made by a WebClient.

I know that my examples can perhaps be solved in better ways (filters for header manipulation for example) but I chose these simple examples to learn about solutions that are related specifically to WebClient manipulation.

I am creating a starter project that all of these projects would use as a parent. Through this project they will obtain their equivalent of `spring-boot-starter-webflux`.

If I would have used a RestTemplate, id simply define it as a bean in the starter dependency project and autowire it in each child project. The problem is that I do not want to have a single WebClient per project, but want to have the ability to build multiple WebClients per project that adhere to these pre-configured configurations, otherwise I would not be able to use the full potential of webflux.

What would be the best way to solve this requirement without limiting myself to a single WebClient instance per application?

Comment: Perhaps the parent provides a builder that wraps the creation of a WebClient?  The builder   would handle the common required configuration internally, and exposes fluent methods for the app specific configuration.

Comment: I imagined that this is a possible approach. Im not sure if its the best or right approach, but if so -  The question now is how do I make `WebClient.build()` return my new builder instead of the default one?  And another question that i didnt specify in my original question - would i still be able to apply custom configurations to a new WebClient if needed?

Answer (score 1):

The [Spring Boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#io.rest-client.webclient) recommends:

> Spring Boot creates and pre-configures a WebClient.Builder for you. It is strongly advised to inject it in your components and use it to create WebClient instances.

The Spring Boot documentation further describes how to [customize the WebClient.Builder](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#io.rest-client.webclient.customization):

> To make the scope of any customizations as narrow as possible, inject the auto-configured WebClient.Builder and then call its methods as required. WebClient.Builder instances are stateful: Any change on the builder is reflected in all clients subsequently created with it. If you want to create several clients with the same builder, you can also consider cloning the builder with `WebClient.Builder other = builder.clone();`.

> To make an application-wide, additive customization to all WebClient.Builder instances, you can declare [WebClientCustomizer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/web/reactive/function/client/WebClientCustomizer.html) beans and change the WebClient.Builder locally at the point of injection.

Answer (score 0):

Follow up from the comments:

provided by the parent - a builder that wraps the `WebClient` builder so common configuration can always be applied.

```
public class StandardWebClientBuilder {
    private static final long CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS = 1000;
    private String baseUrl;

    public static StandardWebClientBuilder builder()  {
        return new StandardWebClientBuilder();
    }

    // provide methods as needed so app can customize some, but not all, properties
    public StandardWebClientBuilder baseUrl(String baseUrl) {
        this.baseUrl = baseUrl;   
        return this;
    }

    public WebClient build() {
        var httpClient = HttpClient.create()
            .option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS );

         return WebClient.builder()
             .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient))
             .baseUrl(baseUrl)
             .build();
     }
}
```

and used by the app - there can be multiple instances, each with their own customization, but all using the standard properties defined by the parent.

```
@Bean("Service1Client")
public WebClient buildService1Client(@Value("service1.baseUrl") String baseUrl) {
    return StandardWebClientBuilder.builder()
       .baseUrl(baseUrl)
       .build();
}

@Bean("Service2Client")
public WebClient buildService2Client(@Value("service2.baseUrl") String baseUrl) {
    return StandardWebClientBuilder.builder()
       .baseUrl(baseUrl)
       .build();
}
```

Other processes, such as code review or static code analysis, would have to ensure `StandardWebClientBuilder` was used by the app instead of directly using `WebClient.builder`.